# Android Lollipin implementation

Tags: java, android, security, passwords, locking

When I launch this app it doesn't ask for a pin code and there are no errors reported either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class StartUI extends AppCompatActivity
    implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

private static final int NeededPermissions = 1000;
String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_ui);
    requestNeededPermissions();
    LockManager<CustomPinActivity> lockManager = LockManager.getInstance();
    lockManager.enableAppLock(this, CustomPinActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify what your question is?

Comment: why app doesn't ask for pin when i launch it?

Comment: using Lollipin library